# Facebook action type Currently Ineligible for Submission error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I wanted to add Open Graph custom story on website. So I add custorm story and action type.

Story: Review a movie
Action type: review

After trial and error I got everything working, I also get approved publish_actions item.

But now it is not leting me submit this review action type for approval. By giving error message

[image: action type error]

> Currently Ineligible for Submission
>   You, or this app's Open Graph Test
>   User, must have published this action at least once.

Answer (score 1):

> You, or this app's Open Graph Test User, must have published this action at least once.

It says what you need to do right there.

So, go *do* it.

Comment: I post a story with name Open Graph Test User but still it is showing same  error.